# What is the "magic sauce" that makes image links work when cut and pasted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images

I migrated [some of my content](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/46587/998) to an alternative answer, but the image links inside the post are not resolving.

They are listed as things like:

![japanese mon][3]

In the text, and then at the bottom, **literally**

`[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcm7O.png`

*Surprisingly*, the images are loading fine here.  I'm not sure what the problem is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must have been a problem with the copy-paste you used. The spaces in front of each of the numbers `[3]` and so forth were not normal spaces. Deleting them and adding in 2 spaces again fixed the problem.

Comment: Adding spaces back isn't necessary btw.

Comment: I like to add them because the image auto-uploader thing adds them. And it looks nicer when editing.

Comment: Copying [the exact source](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/e4b98556-9205-422b-b321-232dedd2506f/view-source) and pasting it here on Meta works though, oddly enough.

Comment: _Interesting_.  I actually used CTRL+X, CTRL+V on this here Windows machine in Chrome.

Comment: [status-rebecca-chernoff-was-here]?